# How is it called if an image is used to encode an URL?

Tags: image, url, terminology

How is it called if an image is used to encode a URL, i.e. the user takes a photograph of a rectangular pixel-scheme, e.g. on an advertisement and gets redirected to the correct website?

This is really hard to find out via Google, so any help would be appreciated.

Could you also provide with some references on how this resolving of 2D-pixel-schemes to a URL works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean a QR-code which is comparable to a barcode.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code

Comment: My question probably seems slightly stupid afterwards, but it is actually quite tricky to google. Anyway, thanks for the quick reply : )

Comment: I would suggest editing this question to show more information. At the very least displaying a QR code within your answer with an explanation as to what it does would be beneficial.